# How can I get the element type that was changed in a form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the element type that was changed in a form using jQuery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

    $("#form1").change(function() {

    alert("some element type was changed")


    });

}

</script>


</head>

<body>
<form id="form1">
<select id="routing">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="ASF">ASF</option>
    <option value="ASFA">ASFA</option>
    <option value="ASFB">ASFB</option>
    <option value="ASFC">ASFC</option>
    <option value="ASFE">ASFE</option>
    <option value="ZSFD">ZSFD</option>
</select>
<br>
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>administrator</option>
    <option>web developer</option>
    <option>graphic artist</option>
    <option>IT professional</option>
    <option>other</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<br>
<textarea id="txtarea1"></textarea>
</form>

</body>

</html
```

>

Comment: What do you mean by element `type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the event object and the target property, then if it is an input type then use the `e.target.type` to get the type of the input

```
$("#form1").change(function (e) {
    var tagName = e.target.tagName,
        type = tagName == 'INPUT' ? e.target.type : tagName;
    console.log("some element type was changed", tagName, type)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yMT82/)